# how to install packages mail and mail_mime (pear)

Tags: php, forms, email, pear, package

I already installed pear to my server by creating and launching 'website.com/go-pear.php' 
However, now i need to install the packages mail and mail-mime and I'm lost. I need these in order to set up a php email form. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 5):

From the console use the following command:

```
pear install <package_name>
```

To install Mail it will be:

```
pear install Mail Mail_Mime
```

Comment: It sounds like you have a configuration issue. Look at the include_path option of your php.ini.

Comment: Im sorry, but I cant even find my php.ini. I looked in .php, user/bin, etc.

Comment: Most often installed in /etc/php.ini. Some systems might move it however. If you run `php -i` you should be able to get the path of the php.ini that is getting loaded.

Comment: I checked the etc folder and no luck. I hate to ask this but where do i run php-i. As you can see I dont have much experience working with the server.

Comment: php -i can be run directly on the console.

Comment: I'm just having no luck with this. All I'm trying to do is create a form that will email me a file. I am using this to allow users to submit their application (which is a word doc.), name, and number.

Comment: You can send messages directly with `mail`, however, that in vulnerable to mail injection attacks. It may also be easier including the pear Mail files in your project direct instead of trying to install them on your server.

Comment: pear package `Net_SMTP` is required by `Mail`